# How to draw half an ellipse in Win2D?

Tags: c++-winrt, win2d

I want to draw either the lower or the upper half of an elliptical arc using Win2D in a C++/winrt app. I can draw the curve, but it includes a diagonal line at its start that looks as if I had begun with a straight line segment - as if the figure didn't begin at the arc but rather some distance down and to the right. How I can restrict drawing to just the arc? Here is the code and an image of the result:

```cpp
float2 arcSize(100, 6);
auto pathBuilder = CanvasPathBuilder(drawingSession.Device());
pathBuilder.BeginFigure(244, 175);
//Starting at 3 o"clock, sweep pi radians, that is, to 9:00
pathBuilder.AddArc(arcSize,50,6,0.0, 3.14);
pathBuilder.EndFigure(CanvasFigureLoop::Open); //Don't close path
auto geometry = CanvasGeometry::CreatePath(pathBuilder);
session.DrawGeometry(geometry,244, 175, Colors::Black(),1.5);
```

[image: The arc looks like it has a handle:]

Comment: Just curious - why has this question acquired a minus-one? There are  no comments or answers that I can see.

Comment: The code is incomplete. Specifically, we cannot see what `startingX` and `startingY` are. Since you appear to be having issues with the *start* of your path, it is vital to see, *what* you are passing as the starting position.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that not only explains the objection to the code but hints at the possible solution. I will edit the question to use actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to that hint from Inspectable I have the solution: the problem lies in where the path begins. In my code I had mistakenly used the proposed arc size as the first argument to AddArc when really that should be the arc center coordinates. And the BeginFigure in the case of this arc must be the point lying at the right edge, at what would be 3:00 in a circle. With the ArcCenter correct in relation to the BeginFigure then AddArc doesn't draw the extra line.
[Update:] p.s. The x and y coordinates for the DrawGeometry call should be zero in this case; that draws it at its original coordinates from BeginFigure, not offset. Maybe this p.s can gain me another -1 for this question.